# Convert ArrayList with Integes to UTF-16 String

Tags: java, string, arraylist, encoding, utf-16

I have an array list which contains integer values.

It looks like `83 0 97 0 109 0 112 0 108 0 101 0`.

And I know that it's UTF-16 encoding.

So I would like to transform it into String `Sample`

Currently when I omit empty values and for remaining I use:

```
String.valueOf(Character.toChars(codePoint));
```

this results in incorrect encoding for non-english letters.

Does anyone knows how to convert such ArrayList into proper UTF-16 String?

Comment: What do those integer values represent?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis code points

Comment: It is UTF-16BE if the higher byte is second. You can just create a byte array with those numbers and then use `new String(b, "UTF-16BE")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public String fromUTF16LE(int... bytes) {
    byte[] b = new byte[bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++) {
        b[i] = (byte) bytes[i];
    }
    return new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
}
```

Evidently the integers are bytes, in little endian order for UTF-16.
One might check that the size is even.
A Decoder might be used for error handling.